# Can't log into PC after removing it from Azure AD

Tags: login, windows-11, azure-activedirectory

I had some trouble with registrations for a computer (timeout when trying to add Windows Hello) so I removed devices from my AAD account.

Unfortunately, I managed to remove a device that should have been left, and now I cannot log into it. And since it was removed, I don't have a bitlocker key in the endpoint manager.

Is there any way that I can access the disk to recover files or re-add it to AD again to be able to login?